# What is the best UI/CSS combination when displaying strings of unknown length?

Tags: css, user-interface, list

I have a list of items that I am displaying in a floated list, with each item in the list at a fixed width so that there's two per row. What is the best practice to prevent this horrible thing from happening:

[alt text http://x01.co.uk/floated_items.gif](http://x01.co.uk/floated_items.gif)

Possibilites:

- Trim to a specified number of characters before displaying the data.  Requires guesswork on how many characters will be "safe".
- Overflow: hidden.  Hacky.
- Remove the background and just have a top border on each item.

Possible but silly:

- Have a scrollbar in each item by doing overflow: auto, this will look horrendous.
- Add a background image to the container.  It's not guaranteed that there's always an equal number of items so this option is out.

Any help on this irritating issue appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you using a fixed font size, i.e. specified in px? If not you also need to consider the various text size options of each browser which is probably going to make the concept of trimming the string redundant. If it is fixed then perhaps seeing how many Ws you can fit in and restricting your text to that -3 and appending an ellipsis, not sure what this list is for so that's one approach.

Personally I'd probably use overflow:hidden as that covers all eventualities and ensures that it'll always keep your layout consistent.

I guess the last option would be to keep a tight control over what can be added to the list and prevent the problem occuring in the first place. Prevention better than cure as they say, although probably unhelpfully.

Answer (score 1):

There are scripts that help with this by comparing the li in blocks of two and making them both equal to the tallest.

Usually, rather than thinking what's best from a css point of view though, you should consider what presentation you want, then get the css/JavaScript to get you to your desired effect.

If this is something that you're just wanting out of the way, consider using a gradient background image that highlights the top of the li and suggests the block without actually filling it in.

---

Adding link to a jQuery solution: [Equalize](http://plugins.jquery.com/project/equalizeCols)

Answer (score 0):

One solution would be to have a alpha-based PNG that would slowly fade the text to the backgroundcolor of your container, on the last 10px or so. That would look good if some text are considerebly shorter than the long ones, however in the case where the text would be equal to the container it could look kinda silly.

Of course, in combination with display: hidden and white-space: no-wrap

Answer (score 0):

From an accessibility point of view it's not a good idea to simply hide the title, since that could hide content on people who increase font sizes due to bad eyesight. Your design should be able to float when hit by bad resolutions or similar obstructions, even if it floats into something less pleasing to the eye.

Now if I understand your issue with the background image correctly, I believe your problem could be solved using the techniques describes in the ALA article on [sliding doors](http://www.alistapart.com/articles/slidingdoors/), where the background image expands with the content.

Answer (score 0):

Here's some controversy for you.. use a table?

Sounds like you have a grid of data to me, would a table answer this problem for you?

It also raises the question, do you actually want the items to be the same height, or just have the same amount of black background behind them? You could apply the black to the row's background, then create the centre white separator with borders and margins.

Answer (score 0):

You could try using:

```
ul li{
  display:block;
  float:left;
  width:6em;
  height:4em;
  background-color:black;
  color:white;
  margin-right:1em;
}
ul{
  height:100%;
  overflow:hidden;
}
div{
  height:3em;
  overflow:hidden;
  background-color:blue;
}
```

Don't know about cross browser consistensy though.
EDIT: This is the html I'm assuming:

```
<div>
<ul>
<li>asdf
<li>asdf trey  tyeu ereyuioquoi
<li>fdas dasf erqwt ytwere r
<li>dfsaklñd s jfañlsdjf ñkljdk ñlfas
<li>ksdflñajñldsafjñlksdjfñalksdfjlkdhfc,v.mxzn
</ul>
</div>
```